# Understanding inequalities in proof of convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

My question has actually been asked before here, but was never answered, so apologies. ([Proof of convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010609/proof-of-convergence-in-probability-implies-convergence-in-distribution)).

The proof goes: Let $X_n$ converge to $X$ in probability, $x$ be a point of continuity of $F_{X}(x)$, and let e>0. Then,

$F_{X_n}(x) = P[X_n <= x](1)$

$P[X_n <= x] = P(X_n <= x)P(|X_n - X|<e) + P(X_n <= x)P(|X_n - X|>=e)$ (2), by the law of total probability,

then (2) $P(X_n <= x)P(|X_n - X|<e) + P(X_n <= x)P(|X_n - X|>=e)$ <= $P[X<=x+e] + P[|X_n - X| >= e)$ (3).

I understand how we go from (1) to (2), but I'm struggling to understand how we go from (2) to (3).

(Feel free to ignore the following if you already understand the question).

I tried to approach figuring it out by deriving the
difference between P(X<=x) and $P(X_n<=x)$, which is $\int_{-\infty}^{x} (|p_{X}(x) - p_{X_n}(x)|) dx$, and then applying the definition of convergence in probability to bound the difference, but my attempt fails:

Let e, d>0. Then for some N, n>=N implies P(|$X_n$ - X| >= e) < d. So I see that I can bound the |$X_n$ - X|

e*(1-d), but I don't see a way of bounding the |$X_n$ - X|>=e part of the distribution that has probability d. Despite knowing probability set functions are integrable on R, I don't know enough about |$X_n$ - X| to properly bound it.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Note that for two events $A$ implies $B$, then $P(A) \le P(B)$. Try to use this to derive the inequality.

Also your application of the law of total probability is incorrect. You cannot split the probabilities in a product (unless you have independence), but should write them as the probability of the joint event.